# Programmatically adding two view controllers to two container views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller that has two containers. I have view controllers for each of these containers. These three view controllers are in different story boards. How do I programmatically add my two view controllers to the two containers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you need to get your storyboards. In order to do this you should use `UIStoryboard` class

```
UIStoryboard *firstStoryboard  = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: @"FirstStoryboardName"  bundle: nil];
UIStoryboard *secondStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: @"SecondStoryboardName" bundle: nil];
UIStoryboard *thirdStoryboard  = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: @"ThirdStoryboardName"  bundle: nil];
```

Next you need to get the initial view controllers fro those storyboards(assuming that firstStoryboard's view controller contains those two containers)

```
UIViewController *secondVC = (UIViewController *)[secondStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
UIViewController *thirdVC  = (UIViewController *)[thirdStoryboard  instantiateInitialViewController];
```

Now add these two view controllers to the containers in the view controller that contains the containers

```
UIViewController *firstVC = (UIViewController *)[firstStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
// TODO: Add secondVC and thirdVC as the children of firstVC
```

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to a different storyboard via

```
[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondVCSrorybradID"];
```

and you should give the VC that you want to create an identifier.

And than you could add it to any frame with addSubview:

Answer (score 0):

So to answer your question about adding the view controllers to the containers...
Container views are just an easy way to add child view controllers in interface builder with segues.

So to do this programatically, first instantiate the view controllers from each respective storyboard (refer to Ch0k018's answer).

The view controllers that belong in the container views then have to be added as child view controllers to the main view controller. You can read about containment here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

```
// Add the child view as subview
childViewController.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds;
[self.containerView addSubview:childViewController.view];
// Need to call these methods to complete  
[self addChildViewController:tableViewController];
[childViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

From Apple docs:

> Here’s what the code does:
>
> It calls the container’s addChildViewController: method to add the child. Calling the addChildViewController: method also calls the child’s willMoveToParentViewController: method automatically.
> It accesses the child’s view property to retrieve the view and adds it to its own view hierarchy. The container sets the child’s size and position before adding the view; containers always choose where the child’s content appears. Although this example does this by explicitly setting the frame, you could also use layout constraints to determine the view’s position.
> It explicitly calls the child’s didMoveToParentViewController: method to signal that the operation is complete.